# Plotting all columns of a matrix on the x-axis

Tags: r, matrix, plot, multiple-columns

I would like to plot all the columns of a matrix separately on the x-axis with the y-axis being the values in the columns of the matrix. To illustrate what I'm looking for when I create the matrix:

```
test=matrix(c(1,4,3,2,3),ncol=5,nrow=5)
```

and plot it using

```
boxplot(test)
```

each boxplot of the columns of the matrix appears separately on the x-axis. What I want is this exactly except for just dots going up the y-axis instead of the boxplot.

Comment: What does *except for just dots going up the y-axis instead of the boxplot* look like?* mean? What dots? where dots?

Comment: Instead of the boxplot I would like the values used in the boxplot as  dots going up in a vertical line. So using my example, on the x-axis I would like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and directly above each I would like 1 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 3 as dots in a vertical line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `reshape2` library to melt data

```
library(reshape2)

test = matrix(c(1, 4, 3, 2, 3), ncol = 5, nrow = 5)

plot(melt(test)[, 2:3])
```

[image]

Comment: This works pretty well for what I need. How come the [, 2:3] in the plot command if I may ask? What do the numbers 2:3 represent?

Comment: @user1836894 see the result of `melt(test)`  it's a dataframe with 3 columns,  first column are values from row names of test, second column are values from column names of test and third column are actual values in test. You wanted to plot column names vs values. hence  `[, 2:3]` which is subsetting result of `melt(test)`

Comment: Consider up voting the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Not that it makes much sense to have data laid out this way, but here it is:

```
test=matrix(c(1,4,3,2,3),ncol=5,nrow=5)
plot(rep(1:5, 5), c(t(test)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`boxplot` has a `plot` argument:

> `plot`
>   if `TRUE` (the default) then a boxplot is produced. If not, the summaries which the boxplots are based on are returned.

The results you are interested in are in the `stats` component.

You could then use  `matpoints` or `matplot(..., type = 'p')`

Note that you must transpose the results to get your desired plot

```
matpoints(t(boxplot(test, plot = FALSE)$stats), pch = 19, col = 'black')
```